# C++ compiler optimization of a loop with pointers copying

Tags: c++, performance, loops, optimization, compiler-optimization

I compile this code on godbolt.org with -O2 and compilers don't optimize it using some memcpy, honestly running the loop.

```
void foo(int* dst, int* src, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

But if I replace "= src[i]" with "= 0" they use memset though. But again, when I replace it with " = 1", they run a loop. Why do they avoid memcpy and memset when the value to be set is not zero? I thought that's one of the first optimizations they will perform.

Comment: Both `g++` and `clang++` seems to optimize `std::copy_n(src, n, dst);` better (and is what you should use anyway)

Comment: I don't think a `memcpy` is ever going to be used with that function signature. If the arrays are overlapping, `memcpy` would cause UB. `memmove` is more likely. With `template<unsigned N>
void foo(int (&dst)[N], int (&src)[N]) { { for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) { dst[i] = src[i]; } }` you get `memcpy` with `clang++` and `rep movsq` with `g++`

Answer (score 3):

The ranges pointed to by `src` and `dest` may overlap, in which case the behavior of `memcpy` would be undefined.  Thus optimizing this function to just call `memcpy` isn't appropriate.

---

`memmove` *would* be appropriate, but its behavior is different from your function when the `src` and `dest` ranges overlap.  Consider the following:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foo(arr + 1, arr, 4);
```

Your function would result in `arr` containing `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` after the call, while `memmove` is specified to result in `arr` containing `{1, 1, 2, 3, 4}`.  Thus the compiler can't optimize `foo` to a call to `memmove` either.

---

C added the `restrict` keyword in C99 to tell the compiler that two ranges won't overlap, but C++ has not adopted that particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the good answer of @MilesBudnek:

`memset` works at the *byte granularity* and you are working with `int` which are generally more than 1 bytes (4 bytes). This is why the compiler cannot easily replace the assignment `= 1` with a memset.

Note also that `-O2` does not enable vectorization for GCC although it apparently does for Clang. `-ftree-vectorize` (included in `-O3`) is needed for GCC to generate much faster SIMD instructions (not as fast as the `memcpy`/`memmove`/`memset` on many platforms).